# If else loop not working how I want it to

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I'm pretty new to javascript and my problem is that when I try to create a button with 2 functions using an if else loop, it doesn't work for me, I have tried other people's code which to me looks the exact same and theirs works. I haven't been able to find anything about what I might be doing wrong.

The button works the first time, changing the image to the second one, but isn't able to revert it to the original when I click it again.

```
<head>
<script>
var btn, photo;
function initButton(){
    btn=document.getElementById("btn");
    photo = document.getElementById("photo");
    btn.addEventListener("click", change);
    function change(){
        if(photo.src = "images/play.png"){
            photo.src = "images/pause.png"
        } else {
            photo.src = "images/play.png"
        }
    }
     }
window.addEventListener("load", initButton);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">photo</button>
    <img src="images/play.png" height="300px" id="photo"/>
</body>
```

Comment: `=` sets/assigns a value. `==`/`===` checks the existing value. Note which of the two you're using in the condition of the `if`. Also, a minor note, but `if` statements are not a type of loop. They do not repeat code.

Comment: `if` is not a looping construct, it is for making decisions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that conditional statement need double equal symbols to make a comparison (else it is an affectation).

It is also a good practice to externalise the function declaration, so that wed have the 2 at the same level.

You should also only compare the current file name (or antoher possibility is to use a boolean var), that I have done by spliting the path by the `/` symbol.

```html
<head>
<script>
var btn, photo;
function change(){
    var parts = photo.src.split("/");
    var result = parts[parts.length - 1]; // get the filename only
    //console.log(result);
    if(result == "play.png"){
        console.log("change to pause");
        photo.src = "images/pause.png";
    } else {
        console.log("change to play");
        photo.src = "images/play.png";
    }
}
    
function initButton(){
    btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    photo = document.getElementById("photo");
    btn.addEventListener("click", change);
}
window.addEventListener("load", initButton);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">photo</button>
    <img src="images/play.png" height="300px" id="photo"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two things:**

1. `if` or `else` is not called a `loop` statement. Its called a `conditional` or `branch` or `decision` statement.
2. Replace `=` with `==` inside `if` condition to make it work. i.e.:

   ```
    function change(){
        if(photo.src == "images/play.png"){
            photo.src = "images/pause.png";
        } 
        else {
            photo.src = "images/play.png";
        }
    }
   ```

**Explanation:**

`=` is for assignment i.e. in simple terms it takes value from it's right side and assigns to left side, and `returns/evaluates` to that value (that is why in your existing code 1st `if` statement will always be executed, as its condition will always be `true`)

where as `==` is for equality check, i.e. if both values on right and left side of this operator are same, it `returns/evaluates` to `true`, otherwise `false`.